# I want to print the date received by json in the morning and afternoon, but only the numeric value 0 is printed

Tags: json

[image]

[image]

i want print
`{"home_code":"A","mdate":"2019-12-13 03:41:01.am"}` or `{"home_code":"A","mdate":"2019-12-13 03:41:01.pm"}` plz help

Comment: Please elaborate your question, currently it is not clear what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: If you look at the first picture, the format of the date is displayed in 2019-12-13 03:41:01.0. I want to print out 2019-12-13 03:41:01.Am like this. I don't know if it's a problem or what's wrong with declaring a date in a string in Java.

Comment: How are you printing the JSON ?

Comment: I use Requestmapping and ResponseBody in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your date field with `@JsonFormat` to provide desired date format

For more detail refer:  https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat